# How do you enter a date time field in Cognito Forms formatted as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Tags: cognito-forms

How do you enter a date time field in Cognito Forms formatted as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

YYYY = 2018
MM = 01 to 12
DD = 01 to 31
HH = 00 to 23
MM = 00 to 59
SS = 00 to 59

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that not only is it impossible to change the display format of a date field, it is also impossible to change the format that it accepts. Lovely!

An option would be to have two separate text fields for date and time, as well as one date field and one time field that have calculations as the default value, inside the calculations they would have to target the applicable text box and format the string itself. This of course is a round about way of doing it, and I don't think the example would even help.